# Doxygen autolink to Java classes not working unless qualified

Tags: java, doxygen

According to the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html#linkclass) "*All words in the documentation that correspond to a documented class and contain at least one non-lower case character will automatically be replaced by a link to the page containing the documentation of the class.*"

I have a class `Wibble` (for example).

None of `Wibble` `\ref Wibble` `\see Wibble` in the text results in a link to the Wibble class.  However, if I qualify the name with **one** level of package, e.g. `pobble.Wibble` `\ref pobble.Wibble`' etc. it all works fine (but looks naff).

**Question**: Is this expected? a bug? or have I missed a setting somewhere?

My settings:

Doxygen version 1.8.5. `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT` is set to YES. There is only one class by the name **Wibble** in the whole codebase, and the *full* package name is com.snooze.banana.pobble whch I *don't* need to specify. The `INPUT` path includes `java/blah/com/snooze/banana/pobble` and `RECURSIVE` is on. Extending the path makes no difference. The `/blah/` is one of three peer folders, but the other two folder paths don't contain a Wibble either.

I know I can hack the naffness out with `\ref pobble.Wibble "Wibble"` but that's so inelegant, and elegance (or at least, ease of getting it right first time without hasslesome formatting) is one of the reasons for using doxygen in the first place.

Comment: No different under 1.8.7 to which I've just updated.

Comment: I am struck by a similar problem, with 1.8.13 and documenting a C++ codebase. `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = YES` but I get the crosslinks only when premending the namespace to each name. This can not be the way it's intended to work

Answer (score 0):

I get it to work but i don't actually have several packages. My guess is though that the actual name is package.class and that is why it doesn't recognise it. It could yield unexpected results if there were several classes with same name and that is why it's not possible. My suggestion would be checking out aliases http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html if you dont want to have to add the package.